# Android Background Service That Runs Forever

Tags: android, service

I need to make an app that will run forever at the background and if needed it opens activity  for user UI. I made an Activity that is the main activity which all it does at it's onCreate is to call to startService(new Intent(this, MainService.class));
The problem is that after the onStart command of the service is being called the MainService class becomes null and it is stops running.

Do I need to start the service in a different way? Should I start a new thread for the service?

Thanks,
Nahum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your want to continue your service running though app gt close.then you need to return STICKY like that. and also need to use **BroadcastReciever**.and your service will not run continuesly because if system need to release memory then it will kill but yes you can restart your service for sure. So i will suggest you to go through whole documentation and stuff of service [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)  and 
[Broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
it may helpful for you. and one thing there are preferences which process will kill first by system and so on..check it out.

Comment: Thanks, If the BroadReciever is not a service, how will it run at the background? As far as I understand an app always starts with an activity. I want to exit the main activity once the app is listening for events.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a new thread in your service and start this service using command [startForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29).

Comment: I want two services to be `onForground`. How can I do that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168209/are-their-any-negatives-impacts-of-launching-two-continues-services-at-the-same

Answer (score -5):

If you want your service to run forever, your code needs to be able to run forever too

```
onStartCommand {
     while (1) {
         ..
         ..
             //call your activity?
         ..
         ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The service should wait for system events (like WiFi connected). Should I still do a while loop or just registering for events kip the service runnig?

Comment: what Smith below said. if you are listening for a system event, check out Intents and BroadcastReceivers. What out what intent is sent when WIFI is connected, and use the BroadcastReceiver to listen for the intent. You don't need a Service for this

Comment: The onStart() should return START_STICKY so if there a while(1) loop there it won't return. Is it OK?

Comment: Thanks lan Low - If I create a BroadcastReceiver then at some place I should call WiFiBroadcastReciever WBR = new WiFiBroadcastReciever(); if I'll won't keep a refrence to it will be collected by the GC. So where should I keep that refrence?

Comment: This works but not recommended since the CPU usage is very high.